# Check if a variable if is even or odd in Imagine Logo

Tags: if-statement, logo-lang

I need to check a variable if it is even or odd and I don't know how to do it in Imagine Logo.

In case that it is not possible, I need at least something like this...

```
if (a = 1 || a = 2 || a = 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this is done by using something that finds the remainder after a division.  Even numbers divided by 2 will have a remainder of 0.  Odd numbers divided by 2 will have a remainder of 1.  If your numbers are negative you might have to pay attention to how the remainder is given back.

I don't know about Imagine Logo specifically, but this [online interpreter](http://www.calormen.com/jslogo/) for 
"a Logo" has three ways to say it (under the "Reference" link):

> ```
> remainder expr expr
> expr % expr
> modulo expr expr
> ```
>
> Outputs the remainder (modulus). For **remainder** and **%** the result has the same sign as the first input; for **modulo** the result has the same sign as a the second input.

Assuming you have these available, then if you want to test if negative numbers are odd or even, it will be easier if you use `remainder` or `%` instead of `modulo`.  So for even:

```
(a % 2) = 0
(remainder a 2) = 0
```

And for odd:

```
(a % 2) = 1
(remainder a 2) = 1
```

You may or may not want to look at the Wikipedia page for ["Modulo operation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).